# jquery ui datepicker no theme on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms, datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker in an asp.net web form, it is working but has no style at all, I can only see the numbers floating over the page.

I have the following scripts in the master page:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I included the jquery-ui using nuget, so I have the themes very similar to
[image]

The date picker is associated to the control:

`<div>Date:&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;</div>`

With the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd/m/yy' });
        });
```

The result is as I mentioned early the calendar without any style.

What I am missing to have the datepicker with some style (theme)?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I have referenced. The datepicker works fine - apart from when you mouseover the arrows and the little white triangle goes gray - and can't be seen. Must have a little graphic missing I guess.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Martin Smellworse advice, based on the the files in my project I included:

```
<link href="Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And worked

Comment: What package from NuGet did you use to get jquery ui?

Comment: @Juanito It's called "jQuery UI (Combined Library)", currently version: 1.11.3